# Scraping Js file with Simple HTML DOM

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

Im using Simple HTML DOM to scrape a Javascript file like this:

```
$html = file_get_html('http://www.The-Javascript-File.js');
echo $html;
```

The problem is that I get this error in console:

```
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: http://www.The-Javascript-File.js
```

Obviously because its a HTML parser('file_get_html')...Is there something I can do with Simple HTML DOM to get the file as a proper js file?

Comment: If the remote URL is a script (and not an HTML page) do you really need to be using Simply HTML DOM? Why not just do $contents = file_get_contents('http://www.The-Javascript-File.js')?

Comment: Wait .. what .. why are you trying to read a JavaScript as HTML? If you just want the file user `file_get_contets`?

Comment: Wait, why you are using that instead of just a file_get_content?

Comment: Because Im stupid, thank you guys:)  I totally forgot about file_get_content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleHTMLDom, as the name indicates is for parsing HTML, not JavaScript. If you want to parse JavaScript, then why not simply use `file_get_contents()`?

```
$js = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/file.js');
//parse it!
```

There's also [UglifyJS](https://github.com/kbjr/UglifyJS.php) (originally based on [parse-js](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/parse-js/)). You may want to check that out, as well.